# Does $geoNear query in MongoDB aggregate pipeline restrict number of documents?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, database

I'm running a *geoNear* query as part of a MongoDB aggregation pipeline, and I can't seem to set a maxDistance large enough that all the results are returned.

I have a collection of about 30000 documents, all with valid geo locations (in the format `[lng , lat]`), and at most I can only seem to get about 9 or 10 thousand documents back.

When I run the following query in the mongo shell, I get a count of about 9000:

```
 db.myCollection.aggregate(
  [{"$geoNear": {"near" : {"type" : "Point", 
                           "coordinates": [-0.1, 50.5]},
                 "distanceField": "data.distance", 
                 "spherical": true, 
                 "maxDistance":100000000
                 "limit":100000}}],    
   {"cursor": {"batchSize": 100000000}}).itcount()  // => ~9000
```

Note, I've set the *maxDistance* to larger than the circumference of the earth (I'm using GeoJSON Point [so maxDistance is in meters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/)).  I've also ensured that the *limit* and *batchSize* are both greater than the number of documents in my collection.

When running this as a *find* query I get the count of the full number of documents in the collection. i.e.

```
 db.myCollection.find({"data.location": 
                               {$near: {$geometry: {type: "Point",                               
                                                    coordinates: [-0.1, 50.5]}, 
                                        $maxDistance: 100000000}}}).count() // => ~30000
```

I also notice that when changing the value of the *coordinates* to search from, I get back different numbers of documents, despite specifying a maxDistance that should encompass everything.

I've reproduced this behaviour with versions 3.2.6 and 3.0.11 of MongoDB.

Is there an upper limit to the value of maxDistance that I don't know about for the aggregate querying?  Or is there something else that's restricting the number of documents returned?  I haven't been able to find any documentation for either of these scenarios.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb geoNear vs near](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537611/mongodb-geonear-vs-near)